# How to select VBA to select button on browser to sign into Gmail?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, navbar

How do I make VBA click the button "Next" on browser? I don't know how to select it.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub MyGmail()

 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

 Dim MyURL As String

 On Error GoTo Err_Clear

 MyURL = "https://www.gmail.com"

 Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer

 MyBrowser.Silent = True

 MyBrowser.navigate MyURL

 MyBrowser.Visible = True

 Do

 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

 Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document

 HTMLDoc.all.identifierId.Value = "testaddress@gmail.com" '''Enter your email idhere


'''this where I'm stuck, I can't figure out how to
'''select for the Next button on GMAIL!



Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: find the Element By.className("RveJvd snByac") then next.click

Comment: Did you try the script @Continue9? What's your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should log you in.

```
Sub MyGmail()

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.gmail.com"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.getElementById("identifierId").Value = "your_email"
        .document.getElementById("identifierNext").Click
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        .document.getElementsByClassName("whsOnd zHQkBf")(0).Value = "your_password"
        .document.getElementById("passwordNext").Click
    End With
End Sub
```